# Can this code be improved it is meant to read and write expenses

Tags: python

Now this code will check if the Data.txt file is already created if not then it will create it then it accepts a user input for what operation does he want to do, Then the user enters the expenses (If they entered W for write) then month and date.
Here is how my code saves the data
624[month:6, date:24, expense624:1200]-624
228[month:2, date:28, expense228:1200]-228
I use the first numbers 624 as the first as month and the second as date, It is also written inside the brackets
To read it I just find the date and month + the '[' the user entered and save it in start and the ']-'(I used - the dash in it because it marks the end or else it would be hard to do) end the same way.
It also checks if there is nothing like the user entered, (find always returns the index -1 when it can't find anything as the program specified) so using this trick I check if the find has returned -1 and then exit the program to avoid errors in reading and writing. The check for correct dates is little bad but I mean its ok for a beginner like me.
Now I want to improve this code. Please tell any ways that I can improve this.

```
import os

FilewritePermission = False
FilereadPermission = False
path = "Data.txt"
# File creation proccess


def createFile():
    print("Creating File")
    with open(path, 'w+') as file:
        print("File created")
        file.close()
    return True


# Checking if file already exists if does not run this
try:
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("File Already Created")
    else:
        print("File not yet created")
        createFile()
except FileNotFoundError as err:
    print(err)
except Exception as er:
    print("An error occured, ")
    print(er)

# Asking the user for the expenses

if (x := str(input("Enter the operation(R for read expense) and (W for write expense)"))).upper() == 'W':
    try:
        data = str(input("Please enter the expenses today:"))
        month = str(
            input("Please enter the month(1 for january, 2 for february and so on)"))
        date = str(input("Please enter the date:"))
        if (int(month) > 12):
            print("Please! Enter numbers below 13")
            print("Ending program, Try Again")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")
        if (int(month) % 2 == 0) and (int(date) > 30):
            print("No! you can't enter dates above 30 in this month")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")
        elif (int(month) % 2 != 0) and (int(date) > 31):
            print("No! you can't enter dates above 31 in this month")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed out due to user error")
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers only please!")
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
        exit()
    else:
        print("Writing...")
        FilewritePermission = True
elif x.upper() == 'R':
    try:
        month = str(
            input("Please enter the month you want to search for(1 for january, 2 for february and so on)"))
        date = str(input("Please enter the date you want to search for:"))
        if (int(month) > 12):
            print("Please! Enter numbers below 13")
            print("Ending program, Try Again")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")
        if (int(month) % 2 == 0) and (int(date) > 30):
            print("No! you can't enter dates above 30 in this month")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")
        elif (int(month) % 2 != 0) and (int(date) > 31):
            print("No! you can't enter dates above 31 in this month")
            raise TimeoutError("Timed out due to user error")
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers only please!")
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
        exit()
    else:
        FilewritePermission = False
        FilereadPermission = True
# Writing the file

if FilewritePermission == True:
    with open(path, 'a+') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        Contents = file.read()
        print("Editing File")
        file.write(
            f"{month}{date}[month:{month}, date:{date}, expense{month}{date}:{data}]-{month}{date}" + '\n')
        print(Contents)
        print(
            f"{month}{date}[month:{month}, date:{date}, expense{month}{date}:{data}]-{month}{date}" + '\n')
        file.close()


if FilereadPermission == True:
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        print("Reading File")
        file.seek(0)
        Contents = file.read()
        print("Done reading")
        start = Contents.find(f'{month}{date}[')
        end = Contents.find(f']-{month}{date}')
        if start == -1 or end == -1:
            print("No expenses recorded for that day")
            exit()
        NewContents = Contents[start:end]
        start = NewContents.find(f'expense{month}{date}')
        Expense = NewContents[start:end]
        print("Total expense = ")
        print(Expense.removeprefix(f'expense{month}{date}:'))
        file.close()
```

Damn that's big

I am trying to get the code to be smaller and easier to understand as this code is really a piece of junk

Comment: Use functions. For instance `read_expense` and `write_expense`. Each function should have a single purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When working with filesystems, [it is easier to ask for forgiveness than to ask permission](https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp/). Your code here has a lot of error handling, but it actually suffers from a race condition:

   ```
   def createFile():
       print("Creating File")
       with open(path, 'w+') as file:
           print("File created")
           file.close()
       return True


   # Checking if file already exists if does not run this
   try:
       if os.path.exists(path):
           print("File Already Created")
       else:
           print("File not yet created")
           createFile()
   except FileNotFoundError as err:
       print(err)
   except Exception as er:
       print("An error occured, ")
       print(er)
   ```

   Because your file creation code checks for file existence before calling createFile() it actually suffers from a [TOCTTOU race condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)!

   Instead, if you simplify all that to just this:

   ```
   open(path, 'a').close()
   ```

   This code is not only shorter, but it is actually much more robust than your original code with all its error handling. Your error handling actually creates an opportunity for errors that actually didn't exist if you just used a simple code.
2. In Python 3, input() always returns a str(), you don't need to cast that to str again.
3. Use inline assignment very sparingly. In general, you should almost always never use the walrus operator with an if-statement, that just makes the code a lot less readable. Just use a regular assignment on a separate line instead:

   ```
   x = input("Enter the operation(R for read expense) and (W for write expense)").upper()
   if x == 'W':
   ```
4. [Working with date time is complex](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca), much more complex than what you can reasonably do in a project, there are lots of pitfalls and assumptions you're always going to do wrong with hand written date handling library. You should always use a datetime library, which fortunately Python does have in its standard library. That replaces all these code:

   ```
   try:
       data = input("Please enter the expenses today:")

       month = input("Please enter the month(1 for january, 2 for february and so on)")
       date = input("Please enter the date:")
       if int(month) > 12:
           print("Please! Enter numbers below 13")
           print("Ending program, Try Again")
           raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")

       if (int(month) % 2 == 0) and (int(date) > 30):
           print("No! you can't enter dates above 30 in this month")
           raise TimeoutError("Timed Out due to User Error")
       elif (int(month) % 2 != 0) and (int(date) > 31):
           print("No! you can't enter dates above 31 in this month")
           raise TimeoutError("Timed out due to user error")

   except ValueError:
       print("Numbers only please!")
   except TimeoutError as e:
       print(e)
       exit()
   else:
       print("Writing...")
       FilewritePermission = True
   ```

   with just this:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   ...

   try:
       month = int(input("Please enter the month(1 for january, 2 for february and so on)"))
       day = int(input("Please enter the date:"))

       # you should probably also ask the year, to handle leap dates correctly
       date = datetime(
           datetime.now().year, month, day
       )
   except ValueError:
       print("invalid date selected")
   ```

   If you can use python-dateutil library, you can be even more precise.
5. Use functions. Rather than copy pasting the date handling code between the Write and Read mode, if you use a function, then you can reuse the same logic between the two.

   ```
   def prompt_date():
       ... code to ask user for date ...
   if x == 'W':
       data = str(input("Please enter the expenses today:"))
       date = prompt_date()
       FilewritePermission = True
   elif x == 'R':

       date = prompt_date()
       FilewritePermission = False
       FilereadPermission = True
   ```
6. If you already use a `with` block, then you don't need to call file.close(). The with-block would already close the file for you, so you can just remove the `file.close()`
7. You're opening the file in `a+` mode, which is append mode. This opens the file with the file cursor at the end of the file, you then seek back to the start of the file to read the file. This is overly complicated. You can just open the file in `r+` mode, which open the file for both read and write but puts the file cursor at the start of the file instead. If you open the file in this mode, you can remove that `file.seek(0)` as well:

   ```
   with open(path, 'r+') as file:
       Contents = file.read()
       print("Editing File")
       file.write(
           f"{month}{date}[month:{month}, date:{date}, expense{month}{date}:{data}]-{month}{date}" + '\n')
       print(Contents)
       print(
           f"{month}{date}[month:{month}, date:{date}, expense{month}{date}:{data}]-{month}{date}" + '\n')
   ```

   Having said that, there is actually one benefit of using `a+` with a seek, which is that it allows you to avoid pre-creating a file and avoids a case of race condition. In the final code below, I'll be using `a+` again in a slightly different way that avoids filesystem races.
8. Your file format is over complicated. Normally, I'd have done this with a csv, but if you insist on using just plain string formatting, I'd have done it with this format:

   ```
   - {month}-{day}: {data}
   ```

   This format allows you to search for `- {month}-{day}:`  to locate records. And since your expenses data cannot contain arbitrary string, but just numbers, the search wouldn't get confused with anything in the data section.

   There are other formats that would've been more compact, but how I've defined it above also has the side benefit of making the file actually fairly human readable, in fact it actually looks very much just like a Markdown list.
9. `str.find()` takes a second parameter which defines where to start the search. This allows you to search for string relative to a previous search.

Putting it all together:

```
import os

from datetime import datetime


def prompt_date():
    try:
        month = int(input("Please enter the month(1 for january, 2 for february and so on): "))
        day = int(input("Please enter the date: "))
    
        # you should probably also ask the year, to handle leap dates correctly
        date = datetime(
            datetime.now().year, month, day
        )
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid date selected")
        exit(-1)
    return date
        
path = "Data.txt"

permission = input("Enter the operation(R for read expense) and (W for write expense): ").upper()

if permission == 'W':
    # Asking the user for the expenses
    data = input("Please enter the expenses today: ")

date = prompt_date()

with open(path, "a+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    contents = file.read()

    if permission == 'W':
        print("Editing File")
        newdata = f"- {date.month}-{date.day}: {data}"
        print(newdata, file=file)
        print(contents, end="")
        print(newdata)

    elif permission == 'R':
    
        start = contents.find(f"- {date.month}-{date.day}: ")
        end = contents.find("\n", start)

        if start == -1 or end == -1:
            print("No expenses recorded for that day")
            exit()

        _, expense = contents[start:end].split(": ")

        print(f"Total expense =", expense)
```

Comment: Thank for such precise explanation to what I can do with my code. I am just a beginner. I have started doing python from like 10-15 days, but I also wanted to know what I can improve as a beginner. I am not familiar with functions so that's why I didn't use them a lot.